# Check 4th elements of an Arraylist and compare it to an element

Tags: java

Check 4th elements of an arraylist and compare it to an element.
example:

1,1,2,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,5,1.

so the 4th elements would be 4,4,1 and I want to compare that those numbers are the same as lets say 4.

I was thinking an if statemet would work. any recomendations?

```
if(array.size(i) == 4)
{

}
```

Comment: _"I was thinking an if statemet would work. any recomendations?"_ Try it with an if statement but first read [tour]: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: So you want to check if every 4th element has the value `4` ?  Sounds like a loop is needed.

Comment: Also learn about `%`   - assuming that you are looping from `0`,   `if (i + 1 % 4 == 0)`  will give you the fourth items

Answer (score 0):

**so the 4th elements would be 4,4,1**  these are not 4th element, instead elements satisfy (index + 1 = 4x).

```
for ( int i= 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
      if ( ( i+1)% 4 == 0) {
       System.out.println(arraylist.get(i ));
  }
```